# Fill Gap SQL Rows By Year and Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table as with below data

```
  CREATE TABLE #Temp(AccountId NVARCHAR(100),Churn NVARCHAR(100), [Month] INT, [Yr] INT)
    Insert Into #Temp Values('Tst05716825','Active',9,2016)
    Insert Into #Temp Values('Tst05716825','Active',12,2016);
    Insert Into #Temp Values('Tst05716825','Suspend',3,2017);
    Insert Into #Temp Values('Tst05716825','Suspend',8,2017);
   Insert Into #Temp Values('Tst05716825','Terminate',10,2017);
    SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Out put as below

```
AccountId   Churn    Month  Yr
Tst05716825 Active   9    2016
Tst05716825 Active   12   2016
Tst05716825 Suspend   3   2017
Tst05716825 Suspend   8   2017
Tst05716825 Terminate 10  2017
```

But i need fill missing year and month by previous value. Need output as below:

```
AccountId   Churn   Month   Yr
Tst05716825 Active  9   2016
Tst05716825 Active  10  2016
Tst05716825 Active  11  2016
Tst05716825 Active  12  2016
Tst05716825 Active  1   2017
Tst05716825 Active  2   2017
Tst05716825 Suspend 3   2017
Tst05716825 Suspend 4   2017
Tst05716825 Suspend 5   2017
Tst05716825 Suspend 6   2017
Tst05716825 Suspend 7   2017
Tst05716825 Suspend 8   2017
Tst05716825 Suspend 9   2017
Tst05716825 Terminate 10  2017
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Do you want to create persistent data for these rows or select them only without having them saved in the database?

Comment: Consider using a Calendar Table: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/

Comment: @NicoHaase: need persistent data. Once Data is ready need to save inside database.

Comment: Why does the row for 8 2017 change from Suspend to Terminate? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: @stickybit: If customer not paid amount first we will make him suspend after few reminder we will terminate customer account.

Comment: So, obviously you have to write some application code for this. Have a try and post what you've tried if you don't succeed - but you have to take the first try on your own

Comment: @Nico I have tried with SSIS script component and its working fine but due to performance issue looking to handle in SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
--first you declare variables to hold minimum date and maximum date
declare @start date, @end date;
select @start = MIN(dt), @end = MAX(dt) from (
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(Yr, [Month], 1) dt FROM #Temp
) a;

--this cte will define complete set of months within range given in table (based on variables)
with cte as (
    select @start dt
    union all
    select DATEADD(month, 1, dt) from cte
    where dt < @end
)

--here you will use cte to left join data from your table,
--then, based on non-null values from your table you'll create grouping column
--that will allow us to specify values for periods of time, when there was no data in your table
select [month], yr,
       MAX(accountid) over (partition by groupingCol) accountid,
       MAX(churn) over (partition by groupingCol) churn
from (
    select c.[month], c.[yr], accountid, churn,
           sum(case when accountid is null then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by (select null) order by c.yr, c.[month]) [groupingCol]
    from (
        select DATEPART(month, dt) [month], DATEPART(YEAR, dt) yr from cte
    ) [c] left join #Temp [t] on [c].[month] = t.[month] and c.[yr] = t.[yr]
) a
```

Comment: But in 8,2017 it should be Terminated. Currently I am getting Suspend

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was my mistake I have updated my ques again and added terminate rows also in table.. I cannot use max as I need Suspend and Terminate both value. Sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: @user3128960 Then my initial answer was correct... Now query works accordingly to your logic.

Comment: its working fine but we have multiple accountid and each accountid have different month interval in that case its taking min and max of whole table. If you can help me to get date interval based upon account id. if u need i can put sample in question.