# Inserting new values into an existing table following a rule

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

[image: table 1].

I need to insert the missing dates between the already existing dates in the table. The value column should get values in the following way: from 2021-10-07 until 2021-10-21 (included) the value should be 9.3, from 2021-10-22 until 2021-11-29 (included) the value should be 9.5, from 2021-11-30 until 2021-12-12 (included) the value should be 10.2 and so on. The rule is that we fill in the new dates with the already existing previous value right until a new value comes up.

I don't know how to go about with this. I would really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: Do some research specifically on a "calendar table" or how to "generate a series" of dates

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There's like at least one answer per day regarding filling out dates, why not spend some time searching existing questions

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It's not about creating the succession of the dates (with this I feel quite comfortable) but about how to correctly identify the existing values and inserting them. If you have any suggestions please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Well again, given a calendar table or a series of dates generated covering your entire range, you can insert where not exists. Have a read of [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then edit your question with more information.

Comment: Well, your version of the question is covered by 90% of the generic filling out questions. for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905794/fill-gap-sql-rows-by-year-and-month or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69780811/return-latest-values-for-each-month-filling-empty-values

Comment: "how to correctly identify the existing values and insert them".  You can use a recursive CTE, when you select the CTE use a Where clause filter for dates not in your table dates.  At that point you only have to worry about selecting the matching values in your table, that's either a subquery or a lag/lead solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example for generating date calendar for missing dates

```
-- test data
create table test (dt date,v float);
insert into test values ('2023-06-01',2.1),('2023-06-05',3.5),('2023-06-12',1.5);

--query
with dates as(
    select dt,lead(dt,1,dt)over(order by dt)nextdt,v,1 as status from test
    union all
    select dateadd(d,1,dt) dt ,nextdt,v,0 as status 
    from dates where dateadd(d,1,dt)<nextdt
)
select  *
from dates 
order by dt
option(maxrecursion 100)
```

Sample result

| dt | nextdt | v | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-01 | 2023-06-05 | 2.1 | 1 |
| 2023-06-02 | 2023-06-05 | 2.1 | 0 |
| 2023-06-03 | 2023-06-05 | 2.1 | 0 |
| 2023-06-04 | 2023-06-05 | 2.1 | 0 |
| 2023-06-05 | 2023-06-12 | 3.5 | 1 |
| 2023-06-06 | 2023-06-12 | 3.5 | 0 |
| 2023-06-07 | 2023-06-12 | 3.5 | 0 |
| 2023-06-08 | 2023-06-12 | 3.5 | 0 |
| 2023-06-09 | 2023-06-12 | 3.5 | 0 |
| 2023-06-10 | 2023-06-12 | 3.5 | 0 |
| 2023-06-11 | 2023-06-12 | 3.5 | 0 |
| 2023-06-12 | 2023-06-12 | 1.5 | 1 |

status=1 - existing, =0 - missing